# With device_preview plugin in Flutter MediaQuery.of(context).size.width doesn't give the emulated phone's witdh

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout

To practice responsive design in Flutter, I have decided to use [device_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview). I tried different phones out. But every time I got the original device's width.

For example, original device's witdh is 1700px but simulated device's witdh is 600px. I cannot get simulated device's witdh.

Are there any settings to fix that issue? Or is it basically how it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I missed a point. In `MaterialApp` we should add `locale` and `builder` to consume simulated devices' screen size.

```dart
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            locale: DevicePreview.of(context).locale,
            builder: DevicePreview.appBuilder,
            home: MyApp());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Along with this, we'll also need to set the useInheritedMediaQuery to true in the material app.

Answer (score 0):

Set your app's useInheritedMediaQuery to true.